# Tiktok Login Kit Integration for web

Tags: authentication, oauth, integration, tiktok, redirect-uri

I am trying to integrate Login Kit with my Node.js app. I am facing redirect issue while the login is successful using tiktok credentials and when the app redirects. Below is the code i have used to integrate the login kit.

**Details of my developer portal application.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA9oG.png)

**Response after successful login**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moM32.png)

**redirect_uri param** - https://2aec-49-206-113-211.in.ngrok.io/test

Comment: I have the same issue. I think we need to wait until the review. Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes we have to proceed only after our app is reviewed. I'll update